# MongoDB: How do I set a null value when totalsalary = ""?

Tags: mongodb, null, data-conversion

Currently, my `total_salaries` and `total_employees` are in String format, and I would like to calculate the average salary by calculating `total_salaries`/`total_employees` . Before that, I'd need to convert the String values to a double. But because some salaries are blank, I have to change them to `null` values first.

Here's my attempt to change to `NULL` values (I don't think its correct though)

```js
db.employee_data.updateMany({"total_salaries": ""},
{$set:{totalsalary: "NULL"}})

db.employee_data.updateMany({"total_employees": ""},
{$set:{totalemployees: "NULL"}})
```

But when I tried to run it, it shows the following error:

```js
db.employee_data.aggregate([
    {$project:{_id:0, "total_salaries": {$convert: { input: "$total_salaries", to: "double"}},"total_employees": {$convert: { input: "$total_employees", to: "double"}}}}])
```

```json
"message" : "Failed to parse number 'NULL' in $convert with no onError value: Did not consume whole number.",
```

I was expecting the salaries to be a `NULL` in Mongodb (just like in SQL) so that I can compute the average salary. I am not sure how I should proceed with this issue.

Comment: Would you show some example documents?  It's a bit confusing since your code refers to `"total_salaries"`, `totalsalary`,`"total_employees"`, and `totalemployees`.  BTW, `null` is valid MongoDB value - "NULL" is also valid, but it's just a string.